# Is it possible to enable yield return on DirectoryInfo.GetFiles?

Tags: c#, yield

I'm calling `GetFiles` and I must return the files found in all nested directories.  I'd like to be able to do something with the found files as they get returned. Is it possible to call GetFiles in a way to allow yield return?  Or is it necessary to roll my own version of `GetFiles` that uses yield return.

I was thinking of something like `DirectoryInfo("MyDir").GetFiles("*.txt",SearchOptions.All).ForEach(dostuff)`

where dostuff is a delegate

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, `DirectoryInfo.EnumerateFiles` returns a lazy-loaded `IEnumerable`

[Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.enumeratefiles.aspx)

Your line would be:

```
(new DirectoryInfo("MyDir")).EnumerateFiles("*.txt",SearchOptions.All).ForEach(dostuff)
```

Comment: Oh thanks. I feel a bit like a vampire but I guess I was pretty close to the right answer...

Comment: @Mr.Manager, yep you just needed a different function.

Comment: I wonder if I will get faster performance with `(new DirectoryInfo("MyDir")).EnumerateFiles("*.txt",SearchOptions.All).where(f=>f.LastWriteTime > Date.Parse("1/1/2014")).ForEach(dostuff)` or Evaulating the LastWriteTime in `DoStuff`??

Comment: @Mr.Manager, You would have to profile it. My gut says `.Where` is either going to be faster or there will be no difference.

Answer (score 9):

Just use `DirectoryInfo("MyDir").EnumerateFiles()`, it already does a `yield return` for you.

It is available from  .NET 4 and returns an `IEnumerable<FileInfo>`.